# cherrypy: turn off sending cookies with static dirs & files

Tags: python, cherrypy

I am developing a web application with CherryPy. I was checking Audits in Chrome browser and it told me to consider "turning of sending cookies with images, scripts and style sheets."

I googled for the topic but no joy. Here is my config:

```
    ...
    ...
    ...
    '/static':
        {
            "tools.caching.on" : True,
            "tools.caching.force" : True,
            "tools.caching.delay" : 0,
            "tools.expires.on" : True,
            "tools.expires.secs" : 60*24*365,
            "tools.gzip.on" : True,
            "tools.gzip.mime_types": ['text/*', 'image/*', 'application/*'],
            "tools.staticdir.on" : True,
            "tools.staticdir.root": abspath(dirname(__file__)),
            "tools.staticdir.dir" : "static"
        },
    ...
    ...
```

To be clear, I don't want to inherit some custom classes. I want to use tools or setting some values above, at best. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am a bit exhausted, that has been invisible to me for an hour.

I just set `"tools.sessions.on": False` in the static dir config section, and voila. No more `"Set-Cookie"` headers for my static content.

Comment: @sedrek, post that as an answer and accept it.  It's something that's stumped me too as a CherryPy user, and I think it'd be very beneficial to share.

Answer (score 2):

Setting `"tools.sessions.on": False` in the static dir config section has fixed the problem.